# Are there any free addins for Outlook 2007 for using snippets?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, plugins

Are there any free addins for Outlook 2007 for using snippets, like [this one](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/EMailSnippetsSetup.aspx) (commercial)?

Comment: "Remark: This software is for free, if it is used for personal or testing purposes; corporate users should register their copy (registration fee 10 EUR)." Do you plan to use it commercially or for your personal use? And 10 euros is not much: it's only 14$.

Comment: I want to use something like this on a few computers in a company i work for. It's kind of strict policy for a commercial software here and, regardless of a price, licensing any software will be a long time task :(. So i'm interesting is it any simple alternative that is completely free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doens't Outlook 2007 have this functionality already, named quickparts? It seems it doesn't have a public store, but looks more or less the same. I found this on the web:
http://lifehacker.com/5031083/save-time-and-typing-with-outlook-2007s-quick-parts

Comment: Thanks, that look promising. Is it any way to substitute email addressant name in such quick part, like %subject% or %name%?

Comment: I have never used it before, so I can't help you there. I just know that the basic functionality is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know that which is your snippets ?
But I think you should try [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows)